# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) When looping

Tags: python, json

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
from threading import Thread
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime
import _thread

webhook = ("https://hooks.slack.com/services/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")

s = requests.session()

payload={"channel": "#bot-monitor", "username": "Astro-bot", "text": "<https://www.astro-bot.io/astro/buyme-asdf-j4wrj-ypzkf|Astro Bot Restock! Click to Purchase>", "icon_emoji": ":rocket:"}


response = s.get('https://www.astro-bot.io/api/commerce/inventory/stock/?crumb=BQXy6KNmMGWENWE3YWQzMTc3MDU5NzE1ODdkNDNiM2RmZTEyNjg4&itemId=5b0dc9172b6a283905dabe08')
data = json.loads(response.text)
stock = data['results'][0]['qtyInStock']

def checkstock():
    response = s.get('https://www.astro-bot.io/api/commerce/inventory/stock/?crumb=BQXy6KNmMGWENWE3YWQzMTc3MDU5NzE1ODdkNDNiM2RmZTEyNjg4&itemId=5b0dc9172b6a283905dabe08')
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    stock = data['results'][0]['qtyInStock']
    print(stock)


def post():
    global stock
    if stock in [0]:
        print("Out of stock! LOL!")
        time.sleep(3)
        checkstock()

    else:
        if stock > (0):
        s.post(webhook, json=payload)


def main():
    checkstock()
    post()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code works once, then when it checks for stock again I'm getting:

> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
>   json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).

Please suggest.

Comment: Please show us the response text before you try to load in as JSON

Comment: confused @cricket_007, what do you mean

Comment: Please edit your post to `print(response.text)` before every attempt to `json.loads(response.text)`... This will help you and us debug the problem (which is that your URL isn't always returning a full JSON body)

Answer (score 0):

I'm striggling to be polite, but the snippet of code is such a collection of antipatterns (globals, duplicate code, code outside functions, bad flow control), so it hardly motivating to do the debugging. The sooner and deeper you refactor that code the better for your project.

Having said that, I think shorter code may do the requested task, and it has no `JSONDecodeError`:

```
import requests
import time

ASTRO_URL = 'https://www.astro-bot.io/api/commerce/inventory/stock/?crumb=BQXy6KNmMGWENWE3YWQzMTc3MDU5NzE1ODdkNDNiM2RmZTEyNjg4&itemId=5b0dc9172b6a283905dabe08'
WEBHOOK_URL = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/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'

def qty_in_stock(url):
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    return data['results'][0]['qtyInStock']    

def do_something():
    pass

def main():
    stock = qty_in_stock(ASTRO_URL)
    if stock == 0:
        print('out ot stock!')
        time.sleep(3)
        stock = qty_in_stock(ASTRO_URL)
        print(stock)
    else:
        do_something()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Random thought, if `ASTRO_URL` is a constant and `qty_in_stock` expects a very particular JSON layout, it's probably not necessary to make the `url` a parameter. It will never be a different URL anyway.

Comment: @Tomalak, you may be right for this particular usecase. I came up with `url` when I thought different urls are used in original code. The intuition is that you may want to read different urls, but for this very specific question you are right.

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak very confused with what i need to do

Comment: @drip man, what direction do you mean? to complete you example, or to structure your code better? for former, you need to change 'do_something()' to your post code, for latter - try analyzing the differences in code and avoid global variables.

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak i see, but how do i get it to loop. the point is for it to be a monitor and keep going till it sees stock

Comment: You can use a combination of 'while True'and 'break'.  The original question was about exceptions, and the was no loop mentioned or implemented.